# ajaxLink and multiple instances of jQuery

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, jquery

I am working in Zend-Framework. I have a layout something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myBeforeSendCallbackJsFunc() {$('#content-loading').show();}
            function myCompleteCallbackJsFunc() {$('#content-loading').hide();}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <?php
            echo $this->ajaxLink("<li>MENU 1</li>", '/controllertest/actionindex', array('update' => '#content', 'beforeSend' => 'myBeforeSendCallbackJsFunc();', 'complete' => 'myCompleteCallbackJsFunc()'), array('format' => 'ajax'));
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->jQuery()->enable()->uiEnable(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this case the ajaxLink function works perfectly.
I fire the MENU 1 and '#content' gets the '/controllertest/actionindex' content.
But if exists ajaxLink functions inside  the'/controllertest/actionindex' it only works if I include again:

```
<?php echo $this->jQuery()->enable()->uiEnable(); ?>
```

Why?

Comment: `uiEnable()` likely outputs event handling code ( not familiar with zend). If event handling code is not using event delegation (which is the best solution), every time you replace elements you have to rebind event handlers. WOuld help to see what browser source code looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the AjaxLink helper repeatedly in some inclusions via ajax I was generating multiple instances of the ajax function created by this helper.

When called asynchronously, the AjaxLink creates confusion.

The solution: don't use AjaxLink, and create a global and unique ajax function.